# Does "The Lord will make you the head and not the tail" mean "you have been the tail, the Lord will make you the head"?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context, phrase-meaning, word-meaning, sentence-meaning

Does "The Lord will make you the head and not the tail" mean "you have been the tail, the Lord will make you the head"?

The former is written in the Bible, and the latter was spoken to me by the Lord.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because we cannot presume to interpret pronouncements of God.

Comment: Some french versions of Deuteronomy 28:13 are similar to English version, but one says "Vous occuperez toujours la position la plus haute, et non une position inférieure, si ...", what gives *You will always hold  the highest position and not a lower position, if ...*.

Comment: @Graffito - well, there you go.

Comment: Why would you post a question about the Bible without giving chapter and verse?

Answer (score 1):

No. The quote from the bible does not mention the past.

In the bible quote, Moses is addressing the people of Israel, before they entered Canaan. The sentence is about the future: Yahweh will make Israel a leader among nations, not a follower. It doesn't say anything about the past.  Of course, you know the bible stories, so you know that the Hebrews had been in Egypt and not free, and the message is appropriate to that context.  However it does not say anything about what Israel had been,  only about what it would be if it followed the commandments.

I could say to a child "If you study, you will be a doctor, not a street cleaner"  it does not mean that they have been a street cleaner.